# Каким образом сделать выборку слов из базы по первой букве

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Каким образом можно сделать выборку из базы MySQL слов, которые начинаются на определенную букву?

Учитывая что буква может быть как рус., так и англ.

P.S. что это расширение устарело - знаю.

Пример обычного запроса с выборкой всех записей:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT `word` FROM `table` WHERE `word` LIKE 'ы%';
```

либо

```
SELECT `word` FROM `table` WHERE LEFT(`word`, 1) = 'ы';
```

либо

```
SELECT `word` FROM `table` WHERE LOCATE(`word`, 'ы') = 1;
```

Comment: спасибо. протестирую - приму ответ. большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Первый вариант самый правильный. Остальные не смогут использовать индекс (при его наличии)

Comment: @Денис Только с collation не промарьяжься...

Comment: а почему 2 и 3 вариант, там и буква и цифра?

Comment: @Денис В первом варианте - просто проверка на соответствие шаблону. Во втором - проверка, что ПЕРВЫЙ символ (отсюда и число) равен заданному. В третьем - проверка, что первый раз заданный символ стоит на ПЕРВОЙ позиции.